# Why is the ReactJS way of mixing code with HTML better design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

All this time, we've been separating HTML, CSS and JavaScript to keep separation of concerns and improve reusability and maintainability. Why are we now going back and mixing them all together with ReactJS?

Comment: Old time php/html mixture a la Wordpress is bad, because it manipulates HTML as a string and has "no idea" about how it is structured. JSX, on the other hand,  integrates HTML into Javascript, and makes both languages work together and obey each other's rules.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a better design, but in the `Introducing JSX` section of the React docs, the same question is posed: `Why JSX?`

The reason the developers behind React prefer having JSX inside the component is that React assumes that the rendering logic is deeply related to event handling, state change, and so on, so instead of separating these two by putting JSX and logic in separate files, React separates concerns and keep the same concern inside one unit called component.

> Instead of artificially separating technologies by putting markup and logic in separate files, React separates concerns with loosely coupled units called “components” that contain both.
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

The docs suggest a talk by Pete Hun on Rethinking best Pratices, which might shine some light into the discussion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7cQ3mrcKaY

Answer (score 0):

Sadly separating all of that is a lot of maintenance when it comes to reusability in templates (building blocks of apps today).

Here is a quick quote of why it's a better design:

> This funny tag syntax is neither a string nor HTML.
>
> It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. We
> recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look
> like. JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the
> full power of JavaScript.
>
> JSX produces React “elements”. We will explore rendering them to the
> DOM in the next section.

[In-depth details](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a backend with React, so it's almost just HTML and CSS in a file (it's JSX which is similar to HTML), involving a few more things like using `map` to show data, but you can separate more things and organise your app better with Redux, because you use actions/reducers/forms in 3 different places.

It's easy to build a project in this way, but it already takes a little time to set up a project. If we wanted to separate HTML and ReactJS as well, it would take much more time to create a base app and it's not necessary.

It's not always good to create more extra layers because the app will become unnecessarily more complex.